# I want to make a key value pair of numeric array in PHP on the base of index

Tags: php, arrays

```
foreach($manualsArray as $manuls){
    for($i=0;$i<=count($manuls);$i++){
        if($i/2 == 0){
            $manuls = 23;
        print($manuls);
        }
        else{
            $manualsArray= 98;
            print($manualsArray);
        }
        print($manualsArray);
    }   
}
```

I want to create key value pairs according to index like 0 is key 1 is value 2 is key 3 is value and so on.
the sample input is write below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  Faucet Centers  
            [1] =>  6, 4, 13, 12, 7, 10, 14, 16, 8, 5, 9, 15, 11 in.
            [2] =>  Flow Rate (GPM)  
            [3] =>  1.2 
            [4] =>  Height  
            [5] =>  5.875 in.
            [6] =>  Max Deck Thickness  
            [7] =>  2.25 in.
            [8] =>  Spout Height  
            [9] =>  3.625 in.
            [10] =>  Spout Reach  
            [11] =>  5 in.  
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by changing your loop to increment by 2 each time and take `$i` as the key and `$i+1` as the value...

```
$output = [];
foreach($manualsArray as $manual){
    $m = [];
    for ( $i = 0; $i < count($manual); $i+=2 )  {
        $m [$manual[$i]] = $manual[$i+1];
    }
    $output [] = $m;
}
print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `array_chunk()`

```
foreach($manualsArray as $manuls){
  foreach( array_chunk($manuls, 2) as $pair) {
    echo 'key: ' . $pair[0] . ' is value: '. $pair[1] . "<br>/n";
  }
}
```

or if you want an associative array

```
$result_array = [];
foreach($manualsArray as $manuls){
  foreach( array_chunk($manuls, 2) as $pair) {
    $result_array[] = [$pair[0] => $pair[1]];
  }
}
var_export($result_array);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Answer (score 0):

Use modulo for that:

```
<?php
   $newarray = array();
   foreach($yourarray[0] as $id => $val){ 
      if($id % 2 == 0){
         $last_index = $val;
      }else{
         $newarray[$last_index] = $val;
      }
   }
?>
```

I assume that your array is the one you have given, so it's 2-dimensional.
If not, use `$yourarray` instead of `$yourarray[0]`.